# Add Bootstrap into Zen sub-theme

Tags: 7, theming

Right now, I am using Zen theme as basic theme for my website. I want to add Bootstrap into my theme because I don't want to use new theme and setup everything.
 
Does anyone know if I can only add these two lines of code to setting instead of downloading every single bootstrap file?

`settings[bootstrap_source] = bootstrapcdn
settings[bootstrap_version] = 2.3.2`

I found the above code in someone's theme setting, but I didn't find the meaning of them. So, I am not sure whether this can be worked.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to understand your question - do you want to add bootstrap (the theme) to your site, or do you try to add the functionality of bootstrap to the Zen theme? The later wont work.

Comment: I am trying to add the theme to my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if I can only add these two lines of code to setting instead of downloading every single bootstrap file?

No, you can't do that. That's a setting from, I would guess, the Bootstrap theme itself. It allows you to choose which version of the framework to use for that theme. The Zen theme would have no reason to add Bootstrap, so no reason to use those settings.

Continuing to use Zen as a theme/sub-theme, and replacing its framework with Bootstrap, doesn't sound like a great idea. You'll have problems/headaches upgrading, and plenty of Zen-isms to remove/re-implement to get it to play nicely with the new framework.

Given that all of that work, and more, has already been done for you, setting up a new theme based on [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) is worth re-considering IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I need to use a new theme.

Answer (score 1):

They both handle responsiveness in different ways so mixing the two together will probably not produce the results you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Sorry but I will give the acceptance to Clive because he replied earlier.